# How can i inject a bean in my controller using spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I tried @Autowired but it doesn't work.

**there is my bean :**

```
@Bean(name = "getModels")
public JSONObject getModels() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return scannerService.getModels(Test.class , Pc.class);
}
```

**and there is my controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/classes", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String getAdminParams() throws JSONException, ClassNotFoundException {

    ApplicationContext context = new 
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(CreateModels.class);
    CreateModels createModels = (CreateModels) context.getBean("getModels");

    return createModels.toString() ;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong in so many ways... I would suggest looking at a simple spring tutorial

Comment: Can you please show the `scannerService` class?

Comment: Don't, ever, create a new application context. Tell us **precisely** what you tried (with the relevant code), and tell us **precisely** how it doesn't work. I have a hard time understanding why you think this JSONObject should be a bean, though.

Comment: @Lino Right? I'm not sure where to start.... first of all, are you getting any errors? What does the scannerService class return? Why is the bean type `JSONObject` and the autowired object type `CreateModels`?

Comment: i have a bean which return a jsonObject , and i want to use this bean in my controller how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve it

there is the bean

```
@Bean("models")
public JSONObject getModels() throws ClassNotFoundException {

    return scannerService.getModels(Test.class , Pc.class);
}
```

and i inject it in my controller

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("models")
JSONObject models;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably how you should've been creating and using the bean:

```
@Service
public class ModelService{ // or whatever
    private final ScannerService scannerService;

    @Autowired
    public ModelService(ScannerService scannerService){
        this.scannerService = scannerService;
    }

    public JSONObject getModels() throws ClassNotFoundException{
        return scannerService.getModels(Test.class, Pc.class);
    }        
}
```

And then in your controller, inject that `ModelService` (or the name you've given):

```
// your annotations
public class Controller{ // your name
    private final ModelService modelService;

    public Controller(ModelService modelService){
        this.modelService = modelService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/classes", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String getAdminParams() throws JSONException, ClassNotFoundException{
        return modelService.getModels().toString();
    }
}
```

This is of course just an example and you'd have to adapt it to work with your current code. But generally it is a very bad idea to provide a value (e.g. the result from `scannerService.getModels()`) as a `@Bean`. A better work around would be to create a holder Object.

Comment: yes , but me i want to load my json object when the app start that's why i make it a bean , and i want to use this jsonObject in my controller . so making a request each time when i want to use my jsonObject is not a good idea